# Using memcpy is causing overwrite of memory to NULL

Tags: c, linux, gcc, memcpy

Issues with memcpy

Working on a C project using Eclipse CDT

The strangest thing is happening! 
When I debug I see that **iu1** values are getting overwritten after two iterations in the for loop.

I have editted this question now.

Please look at the code below.

```
typedef struct IUnitStruct
{
    long ptr;
    char key[1];
}iUnit;





void createInternalNode(internalNode ** n)

{

        int iUnitSizeJump = 1012 ;
        iUnit* iu1 = (iUnit*) malloc(iUnitSizeJump);
        iu1->ptr = -1;
        strcpy(iu1->key,"NullKey1");    

        iUnit* iu2 = (iUnit*) malloc(iUnitSizeJump);
        iu2->ptr = -2;
        strcpy(iu2->key,"NullKey2");

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 8; i=i+2 )
        {
            memcpy(&(*n)->iunit[(i)*(iUnitSizeJump)],iu1,iUnitSizeJump);
            memcpy(&(*n)->iunit[(i+1)*(iUnitSizeJump)],iu2,iUnitSizeJump);
        }
    }   



void printNode(internalNode *n, int iUnitSize)
{

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++ )

    {

        cout << "||Page:" ;

        cout << n->iunit[i*iUnitSize].ptr;

        cout << "|";

        cout << n->iunit[(i*iUnitSize)].key;

        cout << "|| ";

    }


}
```

Here is the Output

```
||Page:-1|NullKey1||

||Page:-2|NullKey2|| 

||Page:0||| 

||Page:-2|NullKey2|| 

||Page:0||| 

||Page:-2|NullKey2||

||Page:0|||

||Page:-2|NullKey2||
```

I need it to show

```
||Page:-1|NullKey1||
```

instead of

```
||Page:0|||
```

Comment: Serious advice: Stop using C/C++, which really does not exist. There is only C and another language named C++. Once you start using C++ correctly, you stop having problems of this kind.

Comment: What is the definitions of `n` and `n->iunit`?

Comment: What is the purpose of iUnitSizeJump? At first glance it looks like you might want to access elements iunit[i], iunit[i+1], rather than with that multiplier.

Comment: What is n? Can you show more details on that?

Comment: Your code is riddled with buffer overflows. When you try to strcpy() data to your structs Key , first malloc() that char[] (which decays into a pointer very fast) with the appropriate size needed for the string. you can use strlen() to get the string size. then malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(stringToCopy)); to reserve the space on the free store for you string. That's just a start.. if there is a sane reason why your indexing into your data structure beyond the size of your data structure ( another buffer overflow ) ... .. *sighs* ..

Comment: Those buffer overflows, will cause the output your getting. Step through the code with the debugger, paying close attention to the memory addresses and their contents.

Comment: Instead of using a struct hack why not set the sizeof key to `1004`? (1012 - (assumed for long) 8 bytes) or better yet `1016` for better alignment? That would eliminate the need for `iUnitSizeJump`.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through `createInternalNode`. Check the contents of `iu1` and `iu2` every step, and the memory location you copy to, before and after the copying. If all of it looks ok, then the error is somewhere between your copying and your printing.

Comment: Actually, the reason why I am doing this is because the size of that unit may change at runtime. So I need to allow the struct data to grow/shrink accordingly. Also, there is no guarantee that I will receive only char values, I can get double or int as well. Hence forced to take this approach

Comment: 1012 was an assumption I started with to test this code. It can be 58 later if I get a string of size 50 and two integers. < The "nullkey" string will be replaced by these key values/sizes if I get it to work. >

Comment: @JuzzJan191: Don't worry about the structure size, and what others are saying about buffer overflows. Using structures like that is common, I've seen it lots of times, and even done it several times my self. Learn how to use [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) to debug applications, and you will quickly find where the error is.

Answer (score -1):

I see at least two potential problems:

- if `(*n)->iunit` hasn't been pre-allocated with at least `8 * iUnitSizeJump` worth of memory, memcpy() is going to be unhappy
- `iu1` and `iu2` are uninitialized (malloc() does not initialize) so you will be copying uninitialized memory into `(*n)->iunit`.  This will not cause the program to crap out, but you will get semi-random stuff due to your memcpy() that will cause each run to be potentially different - probably not your intention.

Comment: Any uninitialized data is past the terminator in the null-terminated string, so shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: I have allocation exactly 8 times iUnitSize and the values in the structure are set to zero automatically. I thought CPP does that. The issue however remains, I am compelled to have `ui1, if I have another unit, `ui3` with the same values as `ui1` and replace the first memcpy statement with `ui3` instead of `ui1` it works perfectly but I cannot do away with the `ui1` malloc statement. Don't understand why.

Comment: @JuzzJan191 CPP is only allocating 1 char for each of your structs. Your stuffing more than 1 char into that memory address. Use new or malloc to allocate the appropriate space needed for memcpy